# what's wrong with my foreach in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, controller

I'm going to pass data in array
but here's the code

```
public  function  test($pid){
        $row_for_menu = Menu::where('parent_id', '=', $pid)->get();
        $menu = array();

        foreach ($row_for_menu as $menu_one_by_one){
            $menu[] = array('title' => $menu_one_by_one->name, 'nodes' => $this->test($menu_one_by_one->id));
        }
        dd($menu);
}

public function index(Request $request)
{
    $this->test(1);

    //$perPage = 25;
    //$menu = Menu::paginate($perPage);
    //return view('admin.menu.index', compact('menu'));
}
```

my foreach in first round worked well 
but in the end responsed [ dd($menu) ] empty array and error 500 !
my english is not well sorry ;)

Comment: it because your recursive function doesn't have base case to break the recursion.

Comment: mishe bishtar tovzih bedin jenab moghadam ;) ??

Comment: Your $row_for_menu = Menu::where('parent_id', '=', $pid)->get(); is empty

Comment: :| is not empty , first round of foreach works well !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the test function must return $menu after foreach like this

```
public  function  test($pid){
        $menus = Menu::where('parent_id', '=', $pid)->get();
        $menu = array();
        foreach ($menus as $menu_one_by_one){
            $menu[] = array('text' => $menu_one_by_one->name, 'nodes' => $this->test($menu_one_by_one->id));
        }
        return $menu;
    }
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $x = $this->test(1);

        dd($menu)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this demo working fine

```
 public  function  test($pid){
    $row_for_menu = Menu::where('parent_id', '=', $pid)->get()->lists('id','name');
    $menu = array();

    //foreach ($row_for_menu as $menu_one_by_one){
        //$menu[] = array('title' => $menu_one_by_one->name, 'nodes' => $this->test($menu_one_by_one->id));
    //}
    dd($menu);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define a relation between your menu items on the model instead of recursively looping to build the menu.

```
// Menu model
public function parent ()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(__CLASS__, 'parent_id');
}

public function children ()
{
    return $this->hasMany(__CLASS__);
}
```

Then in your view:

```
@foreach ($menu->children as $child)
    // $child->name
    // $child->link
@endoreach
```

Your controller would simply be:

```
// assuming you pass a menu id for specific page or similar
public  function index(Request $request) {
    $menu = Menu::find($request->getAttribute('menu_id'))->toArray();
    return view('admin.menu.index', compact('menu'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$menu is empty ie. array() , because $row_for_menu is empty

```
public  function  test($pid){
        $row_for_menu = Menu::where('parent_id', '=', $pid)->get();
        $menu = array();

        foreach ($row_for_menu as $menu_one_by_one){
            $menu[] = array('title' => $menu_one_by_one->name, 'nodes' => $this->test($menu_one_by_one->id));
        }
        if(count($menu)){
           dd($menu);
        }
}

public function index(Request $request)
{
    $this->test(1);

    //$perPage = 25;
    //$menu = Menu::paginate($perPage);
    //return view('admin.menu.index', compact('menu'));
}
```